# [Java]: Get all attributes of a specified type in a class

Tags: java, reflection, set

I've a class A defined as

```
class A {
  Set<String> attribute1;
  Set<String> attribute2;
  .
  .
  .
}
```

I want to create a method that checks if all of the attributes are empty. Apart from a really long if condition, do you have any recommendations how this can be done neatly ?

I tried creating a really long if condition that works, but I want something cleaner.

`if (attribute1.isEmpty() && attribute2.isEmpty() ....)`

Comment: Judging by the [tag:reflection] tag, you already know how to approach this. Have you made an attempt? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm very new to reflection, and tried using the getField() method. But its confusing me. I'm I heading the right way here ? Can you help me with a pseudo-code please ?
Thank you :)

Comment: Instead of `attribute1`, `attribute2`..., put everything into an array: `attribute[0]`, `attribute[1]`... Then checking it as as simple as walking over an array.

Comment: Actually this class maps a config file written in Json to a pojo, so an array isn't possible in this case :). The attribute names have to match the config names, and it also has to match the json schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You can check using two approaches as shown below:*

**1) Using java reflection:**

You can create a method in the class as shown below and check whether all the attributes are null or not.

```
public boolean checkAllAttributesNullOrNot() throws IllegalAccessException {
    boolean allNull = true;
    for (Field f : getClass().getDeclaredFields())
        if (f.get(this) != null 
         && !(f.get(this) instanceof Set && ((Set<?>) f.get(this)).isEmpty())) {
            allNull = false;
            break;
        }
    return allNull;
}
```

**2) Using java 8 stream API:**

You can try the stream API to check whether all the attributes of a class are null or not as shown below:

```
public boolean checkAllAttributesNullOrNot() {
        return Stream.of(attribute1, attribute2, attribute3)
                     .allMatch(x -> x == null || x.isEmpty());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @iamgirdhar. But I don't want to check for null values here. An empty set may not be null.

Comment: I was able to use your second approach. Thanks so much for this: `filter(Objects::nonNull).allMatch(Set::isEmpty)`

Comment: Just curious, how to do this using reflections ?